# Bash syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: bash, syntax

This file is written in bash. When I run it I get this error:

```
./q: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./q: line 7: `done '**strong text**
```

The code is:

```
nohup echo ELMAYET > /dev/null 2> /dev/null && 
if curl -m5 -s --insecure "$1/test/final" | grep "phpshell" > /dev/null;
 then 
echo "$1/test/final.php" | tee -a final.txt; 
fi &

done
```

Comment: What is that `done` doing there? What statement does it belong to?

Comment: what about the other 20 lines?

Comment: This is hardly MCVE, but I'm guessing you need to delete that `&` just before `done`

Comment: i did and this dosn't work

Comment: If it's just a comment then preface it with `#`, e.g. `# done` however since `done`  is a [reserved word](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reserved-Word-Index.html) consider using `# finished` instead.

Comment: user3439894  -- he asked me about the 20 lines

Comment: user3439894  -- he asked me about the 20 lines and i told him that the 20 lines is just comments

Comment: And Etan Reisner asked you why the `done` is there about 2 hours ago. You never answered.

Comment: @PaulEvans: No, an `&` in that context is perfectly legal; it causes the `if ... fi` statement to be executed in the background.

Comment: i rly dont know why done there 
cuz i just get the code from google

Comment: It might help if you could update your question to tell us exactly where you got it from. It looks like you grabbed a subset of the code. If the original code was correct, there must be a `while`, `for`, or `until` somewhere above the chunk you grabbed.

Comment: no no  the code just it that 
no for or no until or while

Comment: Where did you get the code? I just did a Google search for "nohup echo ELMAYET", and only found you asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's nothing else of significance in your script, you simply need to delete the `done`.

`done` is a shell keyword. It's used *only* to mark the end of a `while`, `for`, or `until` loop. If it doesn't mark the end of a loop, it's a syntax error.

Out of curiosity, what did you *think* the `done` was for, and why did you add it to the script? If you assumed you need a `done` to mark the end of the script, that's your mistake. The end of a script doesn't need to be marked in any special way; it's just the end of the file.

Comment: ok that good for right 
but i think the code must give me a result in final.txt file
but no result ?after delete done

Comment: @MohammedNagy: Impossible to tell without more information. The script will append to `final.txt` only if the `curl ... | grep ...` command succeeds. There's no way to guess whether or why it would succeed or fail without *at least* knowing the value of `$1`. (And BTW, I have no idea what that first line `nohup echo ...` is for.)

Comment: ok i'm gonna send u a massege on ur email to give u more information

Comment: @MohammedNagy: Please don't. Post it here so everyone can benefit.

Comment: @MohammedNagy: Then you probably shouldn't share it with me. I'm happy to help here on the site, so everyone can benefit -- and I've already answered your question. If you want private support, I'll have to think about how much to charge (it's likely to be more than I'm worth). If you want help on this site, you need to answer questions in the comments; for example, you say you got the code "from google" (which seems inconsistent with your claim that it's private, unless it's internal Google code), but you haven't said just where it came from.